# Is it possible (and easy) to dehydrate meat in oven?

Tags: meat, oven, food-preservation, dehydrating

I'm looking to buy a stovetop oven since I don't have a regular oven, but the temperature slider of most ovens seem to go from 100C to 230C while dehydrating meat should occur at 70C.

Is it viable to dehydrate meat in an oven by e.g. opening the door slightly as to lower the temperature? Is there another way using an oven?

Comment: If you haven't bought one yet, why not look for one that will go below 100°? Mine starts at 50°

Comment: @Tetsujin I couldn't find any. What is the name of yours?

Comment: Many ovens with convection mode also have modes for proofing dough and other options which would likely work for dehydrating too.

Answer (score 1):

If your oven goes down to the correct temperature then you won't have a problem.  My oven goes down to 75C and I've done plenty of beef jerky with it.  If the oven isn't a convection oven it will take longer and it helps to flip the meat halfway through.

My previous oven was a gas oven that didn't have as precise control of the temperature, so I turned it off when it got too hot and back on again when it cooled down.  You do have to keep an eye on it then, but it is doable.